# Does the Stanley Intelli Sensor have a battery that can be changed?

Tags: drywall, walls

Stanley IntelliSensor unit has not been working.  Needs an answer whether it has a battery that can be changed.  I need to check the walls for studs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it takes a 9-volt battery. And with the cheaper stud finders, anything but a fresh 9-volt battery yields unreliable results.